# Redirecting from child tab to parent tab in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In my Angular application, I want that when the user clicks on edit from the parent tab, a new child tab should open which should have a save button. Now once this save button is clicked I want the user to be redirected to the parent tab and the child tab should be closed. 
Is there anyway this would work if there are several tabs between parent and child tabs.

Comment: But these are 2 different tabs with several tabs in between them. I wanted an idea how to proceed because a lot of people told me it's not possible.

Comment: When you say "tab" what do you mean? Do you mean tabs within the app or separate browser tabs you've opened or something else?

Comment: Separate browser tabs within same app. The first tab is like our parent main tab and when I click on edit button, a new window should open. This is our child. I want to update the parent tab from this child tab. I think I can do that. But when from the child tab  when I click on save button, it should close the current child tab and show the parent tab directly to the user. That's where I don't know how to proceed

Comment: I don't think that's possible. It would require you to control the browser. You can communicate between tabs but not dictate which tabs a user sees when one is closed. You should try to avoid that unless you need to support multiple monitors or something

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative route:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { 
}
onNavigate() {
   router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

Comment: That's what I initially thought would work but it seems he means browser tabs. Restructuring the app to use a single instance and routing seema like the way to go.